# isdigit() isn't working in a simple program?

Tags: c++, encoding, turbo-c++, character-class

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a;
    cout<<"Enter a digit";
    cin>>a;
    if(isdigit(a))
    {
         cout<<"You have entered a digit";
    }
    else
    {
         cout<<"Not a digit";
    }
    getch();
}
```

The code shows no errors, but every time I enter a digit it displays "Not a digit".

Comment: `<iostream.h>`?  What compiler are you using?  The header is `<iostream>`.

Comment: I'm using Turbo C7

Comment: '<iostream.h>'  works fine too tho

Comment: Well it is the year 2016, and Turbo C7 is 25 years old.  Get a modern C++ compiler.  There is no such header is `<iostream.h>` in this day and age of C++.  Also, `isdigit()` is looking for a character representation of the number, not just any number.  What value(s) are you using in the `isdigit` call?

Comment: I've tried using MSTurbo C++ but it doesn't work either...values 0-9

Comment: What is MSTurbo C++?  And you still didn't answer the question is to what values you used.  Also, it works [fine here](http://ideone.com/OhB9fo).

Comment: There is a difference between the number 0 and the character '0'.  You are giving `isdigit` the number 0 instead of the character '0'.  Also, characters themselves have numeric values.  Replace that call with `isdigit(48)` and more than likely you will see that you get it returning 1.  The reason being that the character '0' has an ASCII value of 48 (assuming you're using ASCII).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
```

This code (or your somewhat antiquated variant) reads text from the console and converts that text into an integer value. So if you type `0` at the console, the value of `a` will be `0`, not `'0'`. `isdigit` tells you whether the character value that you pass to it represents a digit, and `0` does not, so the result is almost certainly correct. If you instead read the value into a variable of type `char` you'll get the behavior that you expect.

```
char a;
std::cin >> a;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cin>>a` to extract an integer, will read a number (several digits) from the input and convert it into its binary value.

For example, if you type `10` the value of `a` will be 10.  If you then interpret this value as if it were a character in `isdigit(a)`, it will be understood as the ascii/ansi/utf8 equivalent to for 10, being `'\n'` and this is clearly not a digit.

To get the result you expect, make `a` a char.

Comment: `'\n'` is not required to have the value 10, although it commonly does.

Comment: @PeteBecker you are of course right.  It's just an example which fortunately is true for ascii, ansi and utf8 encoding, EBCDIC being relatively uncommon on windows ;-)

Comment: `'\n'` is a character constant that the **runtime library** treats as a newline character. That is, its value is part of the contract between the compiler and the runtime library. If I write `'\n'` in my source code, its value **does not** depend on what character encoding I might be using at runtime.